# Node Creating new object from inside class method

Tags: php, node.js, ecmascript-6

What is the node version of php's: `new static()`?

In one of my class static methods I have to create a new instance of the same class.

```
class User {
  static find() {
    const newUser = new this(); // new static(); in PHP
  }

}
```

The example above works but I got linting error:

`"new" operators should be used with functions`

Now, I'm wondering what's the correct way to do it?

Tried `new this.constructor()` but it's returning a function not an object.

Comment: I assume you want a generic method rather than hard coding the class name or doesn't this matter?

Comment: Error comes from Sonar?

Comment: @NigelRen your assumption is correct. It's useful when creating a class method that will be inherited by other classes.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Yup, from SonarQube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
const newUser = new this.prototype.constructor();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! I missed the prototype part. Thank you.

Comment: @RenzoSunico you can also add `//NOSONAR` at the end of a line you want SonarQube to ignore (*if you are certain that it is not an issue*)

Comment: I will take note of that. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class by it's class name, even if you're inside of the class itself.
Just like this:

```
class User {
    static find() {
        const newUser = new User();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm avoiding using the class name to instantiate another object inside class method. Do you think there is another way of doing it?